# How to incorporate Google Search Image in mobile app? do we have to use Google Custom Search Engine?

Tags: image, search

we have incorporated google custom search in a mobile app for users to search images only; however due to a limit of 100 images per day (otherwise we have to pay $5 for 1000 images and our app id free and ads free), is there an alternative for searching images only?

Appreciate any input.

Comment: What kinf of mobile app are you talking about?

Comment: it's a photo sharing app with an option to search and upload images from the web.